# UnavailableError: OS Error while training on GC ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I've been attempting to train my model on the GC ML Engine platform, but I'm getting this rather non descriptive error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 360, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 746, in train
    master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 1000, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 989, in managed_session
    start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 726, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
    init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 281, in prepare_session
    sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
UnavailableError: OS Error```
````

This is my ML Engine config file

`trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.6"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerCount: 5
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerCount: 3
  parameterServerType: standard_gpu`

I've been using the ssd_mobilenet_v1 model, and I have modified the default pipeline config file from the object detection GitHub repo by reducing the   `batch_size` to 4 as well as `queue_capacity` 400
  and `min_after_dequeue` 200 in `train_input_reader` on a hunch that it might be a memory issue, but no luck.

I have that exact same stack trace on the replica master as well as all the workers. Has anyone had similar issue before?

Comment: I found a similar issue being reported on GitHub. It may be a gRPC problem; we'll investigate: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17852

Comment: If your code is compatible with TF 1.5, perhaps try using that version for now as a workaround. Otherwise, you can try downgrading the version of grpcio==1.3.0 in your setup.py. (Note, I consider both of these as workarounds and not permanent solutions while we investigate the issue).

Comment: Do you mind sending your project name and job ids to cloudml-feedback@ so we help investigate (e.g., perhaps it is simply OOM -- have you checked the memory usage on https://console.cloud.google.com?)

Comment: (side note: does your model really need gpus in your parameter server? Most models do not and it can save you some money.)

Comment: I have downgraded to TF 1.5 and it seems to be training successfully now. But after a while I get this other error experienced by another user here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/issues/175

PS. thank you pointing out the parameter server type, I have since changed it to `standard`

Comment: Upon further reflection, I wonder if the GPUs in the PS were the problem in the first place (e.g. it takes longer for the machines to come up). Are you willing to run an experiment of trying again with --runtime-version 1.6 without GPUs in the PS?

Comment: I have since removed GPU's from PS'. Which then brought to a Stream Removed error